# Set up LDAP with TYPO3 version 11

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

How can i setup LDAP authentication with TYPO3 in version 11 (11.5.8 to be specific)?

From what i have understood so far, till Typo3 version 10, it was done with an extension, as mentioned in [this documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/p/causal/ig_ldap_sso_auth/3.5/en-us/AdministratorManual/Index.html). But the extension does not support the latest version.

[image: LDAP extension for only valid for old versions]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the time of this answer, there is no ldap plugin available for typo3 version 11.

Answer (score 0):

I would give the branch `feature/TYPO3v11` at GitHub a try https://github.com/xperseguers/t3ext-ig_ldap_sso_auth/tree/feature/TYPO3v11

Comment: A try? Or do you already have promising experience with it under v11?

Comment: Contribute by testing it in this branch and help the extension author to finish the extension for v11. That's open source. The other solution would be to wait or use another extension.

Comment: I don't use the extension at all, sorry